# \SetMathAlphabet messes with \rm

Tags: spacing, latex-base, math-fonts

Please consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}%

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
X$\rm -1$\\
X$\rm -1$\\
X$\rm -1$

\end{document}
```

which results in the following dvi output (Texlive2019):

[image: screenshot of compiled MWE]

Why is the minus in the first line spaced like a binary operator, but like a unary operator in all subsequent lines?

(And I know that i'm not supposed to use plain tex font switches; this code is reduced to show the core problem and is part of a much bigger style sheet that dates back to 2008 and must be backward compatible, so i can't omit the `\rm`. Also, the `X`s in the example are only to show the spacing, it does not belong to the `$-1$`)

Comment: looks okay in the newest latex-dev https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8iMk.png, so I guess it is bug that has been corrected.

Comment: 2008? `\rm` has not been defined by default in latex since 1994....

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is there a way to locally fix this? As mentioned in the OP, the project is ~12years old and still on-going, so a texlive-update is out of the question, i'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you could tell me an alternative switch that doesn't need groups (like `\rmfamily`, which doesn't work in math mode) i'd be very happy to replace it…

Comment: `\sbox0{$\rm$}` after begin document is a workaroud

Comment: Twelve years ago, the command `\rm` had been deprecated for 14 years. I don't think that any software developer would like to support so long time for fixing documents with deprecated commands. Any document using `\SetMathAlphabet` should not use `\rm`.

Comment: @egreg as mentioned above, if anyone can recommend me a math-mode-working equivalent to `\rmfamily`, i'd change it in no time.

Comment: @Lupino You mean in order to write something like `$\rm a+b$` to get the letters upright? Why should one want to do that?

Comment: @egreg The problem in the OP ocurred on the latex-side of a MathML-Renderer. And in MathML, `<mo>` can contain anything, from `∫` to `-`, to letters, etc…I need to make sure that the letters are rendered upright. If I use `\mathrm` for the content of `<mo>`, limits don't work.

Comment: I did not comment on whether you should use it, just pointing out that `\rm` has always done this (if you use a a class that defines it at all) so the backward compatible behaviour with your 2008 document is as you show. Ulrike's answer shows the new behaviour in the October 2020 release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to figure out where a macro is defined? If I use `\show\rm` I get `\protect \rm`. I always thought, this is an indicator of a tex primitive?

Comment: that shows it is a macro. it would say `\rm=\rm` if it were primitive.  By default `\rm ` is not defined at all but `article.cls` defines it for LaTeX2.09 compatibility with `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}`

Comment: try your test file with `\documentclass{scrartcl}` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to add the fix from https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/06692e which resolved [www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3357](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3357)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\document@select@group{#1{#4}}{\expandafter#1\ifx\math@bgroup\bgroup{#4}\else#4\fi}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}%
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
X$\rm -1$\\
X$\rm -1$\\
X$\rm -1$


\end{document}
```